# Python process.call() error

Tags: python, debugging, subprocess

I have OSX and am running the python script out of the Unix shell

I'm running a python code that should open an application. I've been testing with Firefox.app and have been getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/brennan/Desktop/Coding/Wilix/wilix.py", line 453, in <module>
subprocess.call(["open -a "+cp2])
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My code is:

```
subprocess.call(["open -a "+cp2])
```

where cp2 is user input. (Firefox in this case)

if I cd into the programs directory and then do

```
open -a Firefox
```

firefox opens fine.

if I change my code to

```
subprocess.call(["open -a Firefox"])
```

I still get the error message.

Comment: Are you running the code from the Firefox directory?

Comment: The script itself is not in the same directory but earlier on in the script it changes the working directory to the directory Firefox is in. Would that be a problem?

Comment: What about subprocess.call(["open", "-a", "Firefox"])?

Comment: YES thank you Roman Susi subprocess.call(["open","-a",cp2]) worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `open -a Firefox` as one argument, as if you ran this in the shell:

```
$ "open -a Firefox"
```

You need to split up the items:

```
subprocess.call(['open', '-a', 'Firefox'])
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the full path of firefox app.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong to use subprocess.call without `shell=True` or providing command as a list. Please, take a look at first examples in the docs:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Full path to Firefox may be needed or may be not needed.